# How to optimize speed of upload data in firebase Real time DataBase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

im building an app where the user upload profiles that are made of info(strings) and images, Im almost done and started creating the Firebase Real Time Database rules, now its more secure but it has become really slow when I try to upload a profile.

When I had no security the upload time was up to 5 or 6 seg now its from 15 to 20, all the time. and Im just uploading 1 image, my app only allow a max of 5.

A thing to consider is that when the user adds a profile there are 3 nodes where that profile is added, the node of the specific country, a node inside the user Profile, and a GeneralProfiles node, each node has a function whitin the app.

Here are the rules:

```
"rules": {    
    "MainUsers":{    
      "countrys":{    
        "$user_country":{    
          "$user_city":{    
            "Profiles":{    
              ".read":"auth!=null",    
              ".write":"auth!=null && newData.exists()"    
            }    
          }    
        }    

      },       
       "GeneralProfiles":{    
         ".read":"auth!=null",    
         ".write":"auth!=null && newData.exists()"     
       }     
    },
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: Security rules don't impact write performance.  It's something else, probably related the speed of your internet connection.  Also, you should probably store images in Cloud Storage rather than Realtime Database.  A database is not a good place of large binary blobs like images.

Comment: @DougStevenson Sorry I did not specified that , I do store the images in Cloud, in real time I only have de Url, is probably that, today I was exoerimenting lag while gaming, it was just so odd that the perfomance change like that, and the only things that I ve changed were the rules

Comment: Realtime Database security rules doesn't affect Cloud Storage at all.

Comment: Hey Diego. Can you give us something more to go on in order to help you? Any code, timings, log output, etc are going to be useful in order to help. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hey thanks, but its not needed , Doug was right the rules do not affect performance it was a coincidence, today the app was  working at it normal speed, I dont know if I should delete the post.